# Adjacency list c++

Tags: c++, graph, stdvector, adjacency-list

I'm trying to create an adjacency list to store a graph. I'm having some trouble accessing the list once I create it.

```
class Weighted_graph {
private:
    std::vector <std::vector<std::pair<double, int>> > adjacencyList;
    ...
Weighted_graph::Weighted_graph(int n) {
    std::vector <std::vector<std::pair<double, int>> > adjacencyList(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::vector<std::pair<double, int>> row; // Create an empty row
        adjacencyList.push_back(row); 
    }
    ...
}
```

This is how I create the list. Whenever I try to access anything in the list  I get this error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: vector subscript out of range
```

this happens whenever I try to do anything with the lsit, for example, calling:

```
bool Weighted_graph::insert_edge(int i, int j, double d) {
if (!adjacencyList[i].empty()) {
```

or

```
bool Weighted_graph::insert_edge(int i, int j, double d) {
std::cout << adjacencyList[i].front().second
```

Am I creating the list wrong?

Comment: Sure about your `std::vector <std::vector<std::pair<double, int>> > adjacencyList;`'s `size()` and `i < adjacencyList.size()`, as soon you're dereferencing: `adjacencyList[i]`? What does your debugger say?

Answer (score 0):

One apparent issue is that 'adjacencyList, is defined twice. First as a private member of the class, second as a local variable in the constructor with size 'n'. Therefore, when you want to access it as a class member from other member functions, it refers to the first definition not the one initialized in the constructor. Unless you have a particular reason for doing that I suggest to define it only once as a class data member and initialize it in the constructor to dynamically set the size of the vector based on the value of 'n' that comes as a method argument. If so try:

```
class Weighted_graph {
private:
    std::vector <std::vector<std::pair<double, int>> > adjacencyList;
    ...
    Weighted_graph::Weighted_graph(int n) {
    adjacencyList.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::vector<std::pair<double, int>> row; // Create an empty row
        adjacencyList.push_back(row); 
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using MAP instead of vector is more simpler

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<list>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>


using namespace std;

class Graph
{
private:
map<int, list<int> > edges = {};

public:
// Read the Intialized Graph and Create a Adjacency list out of it 
// There could be cases where in the initialized graph <map> link issues are 
not maintained
// for example node 2 to 1 link 
// 2->1
//there needs to be a link then since undirected Graph
// 1->2
Graph(map<int,list<int> > edges)
{
    cout << "Graph is initialized"<<endl;
    //this->edges = edges;
    for (auto it : edges)
    {
        for (auto di = it.second.begin(); di != it.second.end(); di++)
        {
            addEdge(it.first, *di);
        }
    }

}
//Add a vertex to graph map
//structure is
// int => int list
void addVertex(int vertex)
{
    auto search = edges.find(vertex);
    if (search != edges.end()) {
        std::cout << "Already present  " << search->first <<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        list<int> A;
        edges[vertex] = A;
    }

}

//Add Edge from both vertex to each other
// Make sure the nodes are present 
void addEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2)
{
    addVertex(vertex1);
    addVertex(vertex2);
    if (find(edges[vertex1].begin(), edges[vertex1].end(), vertex2) == edges[vertex1].end())
    {
        edges[vertex1].push_back(vertex2);
    }
    if (find(edges[vertex2].begin(), edges[vertex2].end(), vertex1) == edges[vertex2].end())
    {
        edges[vertex2].push_back(vertex1);
    }

}

//Display the graph with vertex and edges 
void display()
{
    for (auto it:edges)
    {
        cout << it.first << "::";
        for (auto di = it.second.begin(); di != it.second.end(); di++)
        {
            cout << "=>" << *di;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

};

```
int main()
{
//A initalized Graph (not in form of adjaceny list
map<int, list<int> > graph{ { 3, {2} },
                            { 4, {5} },
                            { 5, {6} },
                            { 6, {7} },
                            { 7, {7} },
                            { 8, {6} }
                          };
//Default constrcutor takes care of making the initialzed map to adjaceny list
Graph g(graph);
g.addVertex(1);
g.addVertex(2);
g.addVertex(3);
g.addVertex(4);
g.addVertex(4);
g.addEdge(1, 2);
g.addEdge(2, 2);
g.addEdge(2, 3);
g.display();


return 0;
}
```